# Socket Error While Restating Tomcat Sever

Tags: java, tomcat

ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:358)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:434)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:309)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:288)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:98)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:278)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:122)
 at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)
 at com.icesoft.faces.context.NormalModeSerializer.serialize(NormalModeSerializer.java:77)
 at com.icesoft.faces.context.DOMResponseWriter.endDocument(DOMResponseWriter.java:137)
 at com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DFaceletViewHandler.java:283)
 at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:161)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.PageServer$1.respond(PageServer.java:25)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:161)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet$ThreadBlockingRequestResponse.respondWith(ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.java:36)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.PageServer.service(PageServer.java:30)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SingleViewServer.service(SingleViewServer.java:48)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer$Matcher.serviceOnMatch(PathDispatcherServer.java:50)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:19)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.service(ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.java:19)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.service(EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.java:63)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:139)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher$Matcher.serviceOnMatch(PathDispatcher.java:52)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:29)
 at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:82)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've had some clients being served a request at this moment. If it does not happen every time you can safely ignore it.

You can even place a `Filter` around your servlet and try catching the exception so that the logs are not polluted.